# Why can not I re-use SessionStorage when updating its values?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a modal that is a word filter and every user digit in the input it traverses the values ​​in the storage, bringing me the results.

When the user clicks on this link, my algorithm removes the given item from the array and re-inserts the updated values ​​into the storage, but it starts to give error when clicking on the other items in the list found, as it complains about the position of the item removed in the vector ..

**What should I do to get around this problem?**

```
VM6332:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at StorageController.get [as itemToJSON] (WebStorage.ts:31)
    at StorageController.removeItemByIndexOf (WebStorage.ts:59)
    at HTMLLIElement.eval (FilterData.ts:86)
```

**WEBSTORAGE**

```
    export class StorageController {
        protected readonly __typeStorage: string;
        protected readonly __key: string;

        public constructor(readonly typeStorage: string, readonly key: string) {
            this.__typeStorage = typeStorage;
            this.__key = key;
        }

        protected get storage(): Storage {
            switch(this.__typeStorage) {
                case 'local':
                    return localStorage;
                case 'session':
                    return sessionStorage;
            }
        }

        protected get item(): string {
            return this.storage.getItem(this.__key);
        }

        protected get itemToJSON(): JSON {
            return JSON.parse(this.item).sort();
        }

        protected get hasStorageData(): boolean {
            return this.storage ? true : false;
        }

        protected createItem(_data: any): void {
            this.storage.setItem(this.__key, _data);
        }

        protected filterItem(_data: string): Object {
            let _arrItem = (<any>this.itemToJSON);

            return _arrItem.filter((_value: string) => {
                return _value.search(_data.toUpperCase()) !== -1;
            });
        }

        protected filterItemByIndexOf(_data: string): string {
            let _arrItem = (<any>this.itemToJSON),
                itemIndexOf = (<any>this.itemToJSON).indexOf(_data.toUpperCase());
            if (itemIndexOf !== -1) {
                return _arrItem[itemIndexOf];
            }
        }

        protected removeItemByIndexOf(_data: string): void {
            let _arrItem = (<any>this.itemToJSON),
                itemIndexOf = _arrItem.indexOf(_data.toUpperCase());
            if (itemIndexOf !== -1) {
                _arrItem.splice(itemIndexOf, 1);
                this.createItem(_arrItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

**SELECT CONTROLLER**

```
class SelectController {
    // ATTRIBUTES OF THEIR CLASS
    private _filteredData: any;
    private _selectedData: any;
    protected readonly __input: HTMLInputElement;
    protected readonly __listbox: HTMLElement;

    // UTILIZATION OF THE PROCEDURES MADE IN THE MAIN CLASS
    private readonly _storageController: any;
    private readonly _selectedController: any;

    constructor(protected readonly input: string, protected readonly listbox: string, protected readonly storageController: Object, protected readonly selectedController: Object) {
        this.__input   = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(input);
        this.__listbox = document.getElementById(listbox);

        this._storageController  = storageController;
        this._selectedController = selectedController;
    }

    protected set filteredData(_data: any) {
        this._filteredData = _data;
    }

    protected get filteredData(): any {
        return this._filteredData;
    }

    protected set selectedData(_data: string) {
        this._selectedData = _data;
    }

    protected get selectedData(): string {
        return this._selectedData;
    }

    protected get hasFilteredData(): boolean {
        return this.filteredData && this.filteredData.length !== 0 && this.filteredData !== undefined && this.filteredData !== null ? true : false;
    }

    protected init(): void {
        this.search();
        this.renderList();
        this.selectItem();
    }

    protected search(): void {
        this.__input.addEventListener('keyup', (_event: KeyboardEvent) => {
            let typexTextValue = (<any>_event.target).value,
                typedTextSize = typexTextValue.length;

            if (typedTextSize === 2) {
                this.filteredData = this._storageController.filterItemByIndexOf(typexTextValue);
            } else if (typedTextSize > 2) {
                this.filteredData = this._storageController.filterItem(typexTextValue);
            }
        });
    }

    protected renderList(): void {
        this.__input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
            HelpersMethods.cleanHTML(this.__listbox);

            const HAS_LISTBOX_DATA  = this.__listbox.hasChildNodes(),
                  HAS_FILTERED_DATA = this.hasFilteredData;

            if (!HAS_LISTBOX_DATA && HAS_FILTERED_DATA) {
                const FILTERED_DATA_IS_ARRAY = Array.isArray(this.filteredData);

                FILTERED_DATA_IS_ARRAY ? this.filteredData.forEach((_value: string) => this.createHTML(_value)) : this.createHTML(this.filteredData);
            }
        });
    }

    protected createHTML(_value: string): void {
        const CONVERTED_VALUE = HelpersMethods.convertID(_value);
        const HTML_STRUCTURE = 
                    `<li role="option" id="list-unselected-${CONVERTED_VALUE}" class="list-group-item">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                            <div class="flex-fill">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox-${CONVERTED_VALUE}">${_value.toUpperCase()}</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-${CONVERTED_VALUE}" class="form-check-input" value="${_value.toUpperCase()}" data-target="list-unselected-${CONVERTED_VALUE}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>`;

        this.__listbox.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', HTML_STRUCTURE);
    }

    protected selectItem(): void {
        this.__listbox.addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.__listbox.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((_li: HTMLElement) => {
                _li.addEventListener('click', (_event: MouseEvent) => {
                    let elementTarget      = (<any>_event).target,
                        elementTargetType  = elementTarget.type,
                        elementTargetValue = elementTarget.value;

                    if(elementTargetType === 'checkbox') {
                        let elementTargetListID = elementTarget.getAttribute('data-target');

                        this.selectedData = elementTargetValue;
                        this._storageController.removeItemByIndexOf(elementTargetValue);
                        this._selectedController.renderList();

                        HelpersMethods.hideElement(elementTargetListID);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing your code. The exception just tells us that something is wrong but offers very little in terms of "what" or "why" is it wrong.

Comment: Could you add the code with which this error can be reproduced.

Comment: READY, ADD CODE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write back the data to storage, you don't stringify it:

```
this.createItem(_arrItem);
```

...which does:

```
this.storage.setItem(this.__key, _data);
```

You should do:

```
this.createItem(JSON.stringify(_arrItem));
```

Comment: With this I transform again all my array into a string is this? Very good it worked ..

Comment: Yes, the storage can only store string format, so anything else (arrays or other types) needs to be converted. You might consider doing the JSON.parse and JSON.stringify at the lowest level of your class, so it is always done, whatever the type.